# Google Document Update API Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I want to update my google document from my website by text area ( auto save on google docs )

How can I use this? Do I need google access key and where to use the key ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateFile(fileId, fileMetadata, fileData, callback) {
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        // Updating the metadata is optional and you can instead use the value from drive.files.get.
        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
            JSON.stringify(fileMetadata) +
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            base64Data +
            close_delim;

        var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
            'method': 'PUT',
            'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'},
            'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                       },
            'body': multipartRequestBody});

        if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
                 console.log(file)
            };
        }
        request.execute(callback);
    }
}
</script>
```